# Jsoup - How to extract every elements

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to get font information by using Jsoup. For an example:
[image: Sample font]

Below is my code:

```
result = rtfToHtml(new StringReader(streamToString((InputStream)contents.getTransferData(dfRTF))));
                // Example of text extraction from html
                // Parse html
                // String test = result.toString();
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(result);
                // Select first bold text
                String strdoc = doc.toString();
                String words[] = strdoc.split("font-family");
                Element firstBoldElt = doc.select("b").first(); 
                Elements ele = doc.select("body");
                String test = ele.toString();
                Elements all = doc.select("b");
                String boldtext = all.text();
```

By using the code my output will be like below:

```
"<body> 
 <p class="default">
     <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 21pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;">
         <b>Hello World</b>
     </span>
     <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 21pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;">, Testing</span> 
     <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 21pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;">
         <i><b>Font </b></i>
     </span>
     <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 21pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;"> Style</span>
     <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 21pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;">
         <i>Check</i>
     </span>
     <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 10pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;"></span>
</p>   
</body>"
```

I can extract first **BOLD** element or all **BOLD** element but how do I can all element similar like this.

```
<b>Hello World</b>
, Testing
<i><b>Font </b></i>
 Style 
<i>Check</i>
```

Any advice or references is highly appreciated.
**EDITED**

```
<body lang="en-MY" dir="LTR"> 
 <p style="margin-bottom: 0in">
 <font color="#000000"> <font face="ArialMT, serif"> <font size="2">
 <span style="font-style: normal">
 <span style="text-decoration: none">
 <b>BOLD </b>
 </span>
 </span>
 </font></font></font>
 <font color="#000000"><font face="ArialMT, serif"><font size="2">
 <span style="font-style: normal">
 <span style="text-decoration: none">
 <span style="font-weight: normal">
 REGULAR 
 </span>
 </span>
 </span>
 </font></font></font>
 <font color="#000000"><font face="ArialMT, serif"><font size="2">
 <span style="font-style: normal">
 <u>
 <span style="font-weight: normal">
 UNDERLINED
 </span>
 </u>
 </span>
 </font></font></font>
 <font color="#000000"><font face="ArialMT, serif"><font size="2">
 <span style="font-style: normal">
 <span style="text-decoration: none">
 <span style="font-weight: normal"> 
 </span>
 </span>
 </span>
 </font></font></font>
 <font color="#000000"><font face="ArialMT, serif"><font size="2">
 <i>
 <span style="text-decoration: none">
 <span style="font-weight: normal">
 ITALIC
 </span>
 </span>
 </i>
 </font></font></font>
 <font color="#000000"><font face="ArialMT, serif"><font size="2">
 <span style="font-style: normal">
 <span style="text-decoration: none">
 <span style="font-weight: normal"> 
 </span>
 </span>
 </span>
 </font></font></font>
 <font color="#000000"><font face="ArialMT, serif"><font size="2">
 <i>
 <span style="text-decoration: none">
 <b>BOLDITALIC</b>
 </span>
 </i></font>
 </font></font></p>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to extract the text from a document, plus any `<b>` or `<i>` tags (as per your example), consider using the Whitelist class (see [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html)):

```
String html = "<body><p class='default'> <span style='color: #000000; font-size: 21pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;'> <b>Hello World</b> </span> <span style='color: #000000; font-size: 21pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;'> , Testing </span> <span style='color: #000000; font-size: 21pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;'> <i><b>Font </b></i> </span> <span style='color: #000000; font-size: 21pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;'> Style </span> <span style='color: #000000; font-size: 21pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;'> <i>Check</i> </span> <span style='color: #000000; font-size: 10pt; font-family: MyriadPro-Bold;'> </span> </p></body>";

Whitelist wl = Whitelist.simpleText();
wl.addTags("b", "i"); // add additional tags here as necessary
String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, wl);
System.out.println(clean);
```

Which will output (as per your example):

```
11-07 19:04:45.738: I/System.out(318): <b>Hello World</b>   , Testing   
11-07 19:04:45.738: I/System.out(318): <i><b>Font </b></i>   Style   
11-07 19:04:45.738: I/System.out(318): <i>Check</i>
```

---

Update:

```
ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();

Elements e = doc.select("span");

for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++) {
    elements.add(e.get(i).html());
}
```

Comment: any idea how I can split this to array or array list. Like `array[0] = <b>Hello World</b>`, `array[1] = , Testing`,  `array [2]= i><b>Font </b></i>`

Comment: see my new code, adding each of those to an ArrayList. Let me know if it has to be a String[] array...

Comment: I have edited my question. `Elements e = doc.select("span");` not able to generate the output. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your selector to the `<p>` tag like so:
`Element all = doc.select("p").first();`

Then you need to get all the children of that element.

```
String myString = "";
for(Element item : all.children()) {
    myString += item.text();
}
```

I am assuming you want the text inside the tags, and not the tags themselves.

Alternatively you could do.

```
Elements all = doc.select("b");
all.addAll(doc.select("i"));
all.addAll(doc.select("span"));
String myString = all.text();
```

Comment: in my code `all` is refering to **bold** value only but I want to do every element, not only Bolded

Comment: I see, then you want your selector to be the <p> tag and get all child elements of that i will update my answer to show

Comment: error= `no suitable method found for add(Elements)
    method Elements.add(int,Element) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Elements.add(Element) is not applicable
      (actual argument Elements cannot be converted to Element by method invocation conversion)
----`

Comment: sorry it is `addAll` not `add`