# How to extract font tag from HTML?

Tags: java, android, html

I’m tring to extract the font face name e.g.:

```
String htmlContent = "<font face=\"impact\">Hdjdjdisid <font style=\"background-color:#ff0000\"> shejej</font></font>";
```

to:

```
impact
```

This is what I found on the web but it’s returning all the tags’ content and i want only the `face` name.

```
String pattern = "<FONT (.*?)>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(htmlContent);

if (m.find()) {
    // prints: <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12"> My Name is xyz </FONT></P>
    System.out.println(m.group());

    // prints: FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12"
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

How can I extract only the face name?

Comment: Why don't you use an HTML parser such as jsoup?

Comment: *[Even Jon Skeet cannot parse HTML using regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)*

Comment: jsoup extract elements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831558/jsoup-how-to-extract-every-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this simple case, adjust your pattern like this:

```
<font[^>]+face="([^"]+)"
```

escaped for use with java:

```
String pattern = "<font[^>]+face=\"([^\"]+)\"";
```

But as others pointed out: dont parse html with regex.